# how to style a particular column of each row of a table to not dispaly their border

Tags: html, css

Here is my table

```
<table  border ="1" width="1253" style="margin-left:30px;">
      <tr>
        <td width="40" height="40"></td>
        <td width="5" height="40"></td>
        <td width="30" height="40"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="40" height="40"></td>
        <td width="5" height="40"></td>
        <td width="30" height="40"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="40" height="40"></td>
        <td width="5" height="40"></td>
        <td width="30" eight="40"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="40" height="40"></td>
        <td width="5" height="40"></td>
        <td width="30" height="40"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="40" height="40"></td>
        <td width="5" height="40"></td>
        <td width="30" height="40"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

here is my css

```
 table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-style: hidden;
}

table td, table th {
    border: 1px solid #0082C1;
}
```

by doing so i can display the table without any outer border but i want to make it look like two tables,that mean the middle column of each row should not display.please help me.
i have tried two take two tables in one line by taking the property display:inline-block,but it didn't worked properly as it displayed the outer border also.

Comment: You mean something like http://jsfiddle.net/eJD5c/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/78nsW/)

Try:

```
//remove borders on second column

    table tr td:nth-child(2) 
    { 
    border:none; 
    }

//remove left and right borders

table td, table th {
    border-top: 1px solid #0082C1;
    border-left:none;
    border-right:none;
}
```

Comment: And here are some useful nth-child recipes: http://css-tricks.com/useful-nth-child-recipies/

Answer (score 1):

Try to add the following style:

```
table td:nth-child(2), table th:nth-child(2) {
    border: none;
}
```

But be aware that `nth-child` has limited support. It doesn't work for IE8 and older.

Comment: it removed only bottom border.

Comment: @HimanshuSamantaray side borders are also removed. These borders you see are the borders belonging to first and third table cells.